# Uncaught TypeError: Object function ()

Tags: javascript, extjs

I wrote the following functions. At run time the browser complains about uncaught TypeError ...has no method 'init'. What's wrong of my code?

```
function build_results_grid (response) {

        // build grid
        grid_ui.init();

    } // build the results grid

    var grid_ui = function () {

        return {
            init: function () {
               //build_grid();
            }
      }; // return
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You assigned `grid_ui` to a function, without calling it.

Change that to

```
var grid_ui = (function() { ... })();
```

Answer (score 3):

since a call to grid_ui is necessary to return the function with init inside, you need

```
    grid_ui().init();
```

Since grid_ui must be called.  Or you can make `grid_ui` be the return of the call, as SLaks did

EDIT - I misread your braces, if you noticed the question I had here before you can disregard it.